# difference between reactJs and create-react-app website

Tags: reactjs, web, web-deployment

**what is the difference between** *https://reactjs.org* **and** *https://create-react-app.dev* **website. This websites is used for which purpose? Learning or others? and which will learn me react?**

Comment: create-react-app is just a starter template for react project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't know why https://create-react-app.dev has been build but I can tell you one thing that https://reactjs.org is the official site of React. So I think you should go with https://reactjs.org and it will help you to learn to react. See the documentation there.